Computing and Representing Skyrmions for Different Models
Are there any example models for which Skyrmions can be explicitly constructed? Or at least a procedure where I can find analytical expressions that approximate them like a series expansion, etc. I'm most interested in micromagnetics modeled, e.g., by the Landau-Lifshitz equation:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau–Lifshitz–Gilbert_equation
